# Foreground services and repetitive tasks which need to be executed on time

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app which basically performs some tasks on timer tick (in this case - searching for beacons) and sends results to the server. My goal was to create an app which does its job constantly in the background. Fortunately, I'm using logging all over the code, so when we started to test it we found that sometime later the timer's callback wasn't being called on time. There were some pauses which obviously had been caused by standby and doze mode. At that moment I was using a background service and System.Threading.Timer. Then, after some research, I rewrote the services to use Alarm Manager + Wake locks, but the pauses were still there. The next try was to make the service foreground and use it with a Handler to post delayed tasks and everything seemed to be fine while the device was connected to the computer. When the device is not connected to a charger those pauses are here again. The interesting thing is that we cannot actually predict this behavior. Sometimes it works perfectly fine and sometimes not. And this is really strange because the code to schedule it is pretty simple and straightforward:

```
...

private int scanThreadsCount = 0;
private Android.OS.Handler handler = new Android.OS.Handler();

private bool LocationInProgress
{
    get { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref scanThreadsCount, 0, 0) != 0; }
}

public void ForceLocation()
{
    if (!LocationInProgress) DoLocation();
}

private async void DoLocation()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref scanThreadsCount);
    Logger.Debug("Location is started");

    try
    {
        // Location...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.Error(e, "Location cannot be performed due to an unexpected error");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (LocationInterval > 0)
        {
            # It's here. The location interval is 60 seconds
            # and the service is running in the foreground!
            # But in the screenshot we can see the delay which 
            # sometimes reaches 10 minutes or even more

            handler.PostDelayed(ForceLocation, LocationInterval * 1000);
        }

        Logger.Debug("Location has been finished");
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref scanThreadsCount);
    }
}

...
```

Actually it can be ok, but I need that service to do its job strictly on time, but the callback is being called with a few seconds delay or a few minutes and that's not acceptable.

The Android documentation says that foreground services are not restricted by standby and doze mode, but I cannot really find the cause of that strange behavior. Why is the callback not being called on time? Where do these 10 minutes pauses come from? It's pretty frustrating because I cannot move further unless I have the robust basis. Does anybody know the reason of such a strange behavior or any suggestions how I can achieve the callback to be executed on time?

P.S. The current version of the app is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uedrbk31db7h415/project.zip?dl=0). I know, it's quite boring trying to figure out what is wrong with one's code, but there are only 3 files which have to do with that problem:

```
~/Services/BeaconService.cs  
~/Services/BeaconServiceScanFunctionality.cs  
~/Services/BeaconServiceSyncFunctionality.cs
```

The project was provided for those who would probably want to try it in action and figure it out by themselves.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is Customer code?

Comment: The customer code it's just a string to identify our customer. In order to run it modify the `Task<bool> UserManager.Login(string customerCode)` method to create an empty object.

Comment: Then I crash when app tries to use Profile because it is null

Comment: When I create profile and empty settings and try to login in it sends me back to login window. Sorry, I need to do too many tweaks to debug your code.

Comment: Actually, that's all you need: [click](https://pastebin.com/MdcVswJF)

Comment: Crash:                 ServicesManager.BeaconsService.EnableCoreFunctionality(AuthManager.Profile.Settings); Below setting is null SetSynchronizationInterval(settings.DbSynchronizationInterval);

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about this. The right version is `Profile = new UserProfile() { Settings = new UserSettings() }`

Comment: it doesn't help. App crashes in OnStart of MainActivity even before login here ServicesManager.BeaconsService.EnableCoreFunctionality(AuthManager.Profile.Settings);